# long if else loop and recoding in R

Tags: r, loops

I know my problem is simple but not for me. Here is small dataset.

```
mark1 <- c("AB", "BB", "AB", "BB", "BB", "AB", "--", "BB")
mark2 <- c("AB", "AB", "AA", "BB", "BB", "AA", "--", "BB")
mark3 <- c("BB", "AB", "AA", "BB", "BB", "AA", "--", "BB")
mark4 <- c("AA", "AB", "AA", "BB", "BB", "AA", "--", "BB")
mark5 <- c("AB", "AB", "AA", "BB", "BB", "AA", "--", "BB")
mark6 <- c("--", "BB", "AA", "BB", "BB", "AA", "--", "BB")
mark7 <- c("AB", "--", "AA", "BB", "BB", "AA", "--", "BB")
mark8 <- c("BB", "AA", "AA", "BB", "BB", "AA", "--", "BB")
mymark <- data.frame (mark1, mark2, mark3, mark4, mark5, mark6, mark7, mark8)
tmymark <- data.frame (t(mymark))
names (tmymark) <- c("P1", "P2","I1", "I2", "I3", "I4", "KL", "MN")
```

Thus dataset becomes:

```
      P1 P2 I1 I2 I3 I4 KL MN
mark1 AB BB AB BB BB AB -- BB
mark2 AB AB AA BB BB AA -- BB
mark3 BB AB AA BB BB AA -- BB
mark4 AA AB AA BB BB AA -- BB
mark5 AB AB AA BB BB AA -- BB
mark6 -- BB AA BB BB AA -- BB
mark7 AB -- AA BB BB AA -- BB
mark8 BB AA AA BB BB AA -- BB
```

I want to classify mark1:8 based on the P1 and P2 comparision and provide a code, which will make a new variable:

```
loctype <- NULL

if (tmymark$P1 == "AB" &  tmymark$P2 == "AB"){
       loctype = "<hkxhk>"
       } else {
if (tmymark$P1== "AB" & tmymark$P2 == "BB") {
      loctype = "<lmxll>"
      } else {
      if (tmymark$P1 == "AA" & tmymark$P2 == "AB") {
       loctype = "<nnxnp>"
       } else {
        if (tmymark$P1 == "AA" & tmymark$P2 == "BB") {
        loctype = "MN"
        } else {
        if (tmymark$P1 == "BB" & tmymark$P2 == "AA"){
         loctype = "MN"
         } else {
         if (tmymark$P1 == "--" & tmymark$P2 == "AA"){
         loctype = "NR"
         }  else {
if (tmymark$P1 == "AA" & tmymark$P2 == "--"){
          loctype = "NR"
} else {
    cat ("error wrong input in P1 or P2")
    }} }}}}}
```

Here what I am trying to do it compare P1 and P2 values and generated a new variable. 
for examp, if tmymark$P1 == "AB" &  tmymark$P2 == "AB" the loctype should be "". If not the second condition will be application and so on.

Here is my error message.

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (tmymark$P1 == "AB" & tmymark$P2 == "AB") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (tmymark$P1 == "AB" & tmymark$P2 == "BB") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Once loctype vector is generated I want to recode the tmymark with the information in this variable:

```
tmymark1 <- data.frame (loctype, tmymark)      
require(car) 
for(i in 2:length(tmymark)){

        if (loctype = "<hkxhk>") {
       tmymark[[i]] <- recode (x, "AB" = "hk", "BA" = "hk", "AA" = "hh", "BB" = "kk")
       } else {
       if (loctype = "<lmxll>") {
       tmymark[[i]] <- recode ((x, "AB" = "lm", "BA" = "lm", "AA" = "--", "BB" = "kk")
       } else {

        if (loctype = "<nnxnp>") {
       tmymark[[i]] <- recode ((x, "AB" = "np", "BA" = "np", "AA" = "nn", "BB" = "--")
             } else {
       if (loctype = "MN") {
        tmymark[[i]] <- "--"
       } esle {
      if (loctype = "NR") {
        tmymark[[i]] <- "NA"
       } else {
       cat ("error wrong input code")
      } } }}}
```

Am I on right track ?

Edits: Expected output

```
      loctype  P1 P2 I1 I2 I3 I4 KL MN 
mark1  <lmxmm> lm mm lm mm mm lm -- mm 
mark2  <hkxhk> hk hk hh kk kk hh -- kk 
mark3 <nnxnp> nn np nn -- -- nn -- -- 
 and so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match` is definitely the way to go.  I'd make two data frames as keys, like this:

```
key <- data.frame(
             P1=c("AB", "AB", "AA", "AA", "BB", "--", "AA"),
             P2=c("AB", "BB", "AB", "BB", "AA", "AA", "--"),
             loctype=c("<hkxhk>", "<lmxll>", "<nnxnp>", "MN", "MN", "NR", "NR"))

key2 <- cbind(
  `<hkxhk>` = c("hk","hk","hh","kk"),
  `<lmxll>` = c("lm", "lm", "--", "kk"),
  `<nnxnp>` = c("np", "np", "nn", "--"),
  MN = rep("--", 4),
  NR = rep("NA", 4) )
rownames(key2) = c("AB","BA", "AA", "BB")
```

and then use `match` on `key1` to get the `loctype` (as Justin also recommends), and also on both the rownames and columns of `key2` to get the desired substitution, using matrix indexing to get the desired value from the key.

```
loctype <- key$loctype[match(with(tmymark, paste(P1, P2, sep="\b")), 
                             with(key, paste(P1, P2, sep="\b")))]
ii <- match(as.vector(as.matrix(tmymark)), rownames(key2))
jj <- rep(match(loctype, colnames(key2)), nrow(tmymark))
out <- as.data.frame(matrix(key2[cbind(ii,jj)], nrow=nrow(tmymark)))
colnames(out) <- colnames(tmymark)
rownames(out) <- rownames(tmymark)
out$loctype <- loctype
```

The result then looks like this, where the missing values are because I don't have values for those combinations in my keys.

```
> print(out, na="")
      P1 P2 I1 I2 I3 I4 KL MN loctype
mark1 lm kk lm kk kk lm    kk <lmxll>
mark2 hk hk hh kk kk hh    kk <hkxhk>
mark3                                
mark4 nn np nn -- -- nn    -- <nnxnp>
mark5 hk hk hh kk kk hh    kk <hkxhk>
mark6                                
mark7                                
mark8 -- -- -- -- -- --    --      MN
```

Answer (score 1):

your first error occurs since if wants a single logical value (or expression that evaluates to one).  You can use `ifelse( )` instead which is a "vectorized" `if`

```
ifelse(tmymark$P1 == "AB" &  tmymark$P2 == "AB", loctype = "<hkxhk>", else clauses...)
```

To avoid the long `if() else()` structure (or `ifelse()` as it were), you can use match.  make a data frame of your expected combinations of P1 and P2 and add a column for the desired loctype:

```
matches <- data.frame(p1p2 = c('AB AB', 'AB BB', 'AA AB', 'AA BB', 'BB AA', '-- AA', 'AA --'),
                      loctype = c('<hkxhk>', '<lmxll>', '<nnxnp>', 'MN', 'MN', 'NR', 'NR'))
loctype <- matches$loctype[match(paste(tmymark$P1, tmymark$P2), matches$p1p2),]
```

The second portion could be done a number of ways, but I'm drawing a blank on a "neat and tidy' one.