# alternative to a number of if else loop in r

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I have a table of conditions and coformula to be used based on the condition:

```
MTR                 CLD                     AF                 PI
AA                  AA                     AB                   0.5/a      (cond1)
AA                  AB                     AB                  0.5/a      (cond2)
AB                  AA                     AB                   0.5 /a     (cond3)
AA                  AA                     AA                    1/a   (cond4)
AB                  AA                     AA                     1/a   (cond5)
BB                  AB                     AA                    1/a  (cond6)
AB                  AB                     AA                    1/(a+b) (cond7)
AB                  AB                     AB                    1/(a+b)  (cond8)
```

If there is not match of conditions should yield "NA".

```
 # table of conditions 
MTR <- c("AA",  "AA",   "AB",   "AA",   "AB",   "BB",   "AB",   "AB")
CLD <- c("AA",  "AB",   "AA",   "AA",   "AA",   "AB",   "AB",   "AB")
AF <- c("AB",   "AB",   "AB",   "AA",   "AA",   "AA",   "AA",   "AB")
PI <- c("0.5/a",    "0.5/a",    "0.5/a",    "1/a",  "1/a",  "1/a",  
      "1/(a+b)",    "1/(a+b)")
```

Here are two datasets to be applied:

```
# the dataset to be applied to 
dataf <- data.frame (MTR = c("AB", "BB", "AB", "BB", "AB", "AA"),
                     CLD= c("AA", "AB", "AA", "AB", "AB", "AB"),
                     AF = c("AA", "AB", "BB", "AB", "BB", "AB")
                     )


     MTR CLD AF
1  AB  AA AA 
2  BB  AB AB 
3  AB  AA BB
4  BB  AB AB
5  AB  AB BB
6  AA  AB AB

a = c(0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4)
mapd <- data.frame(a = a, b = 1-a)
```

Edits: Following the suggestion down, I can combine the two dataframes into one:
newdf <- data.frame (dataf, mapd)

```
 MTR CLD AF   a   b
1  AB  AA AA 0.5 0.5
2  BB  AB AB 0.4 0.6
3  AB  AA BB 0.3 0.7
4  BB  AB AB 0.5 0.5
5  AB  AB BB 0.2 0.8
6  AA  AB AB 0.4 0.6
```

I think that I can solve this by creating if else - but there are many conditions I am not sure that this is only (good) way to do.

```
 PI = NULL
 if (dataf$MTR = "AA", dataf$CLD = "AA", dataf$AF = "AB") {
                          PI =  0.5/mapd$a } else {
  if (dataf$MTR = "AA", dataf$CLD = "AB", dataf$AF = "AB"){
                          PI =  0.5/mapd$a
                          } else {
         ............. so on
```

Is there is any alternative to this ?

Comment: You can look at `ifelse()` which is vectorized, and `switch()` may be good for you too.

Comment: Your test `dataf object has a lot of rows with no possible match to your table of conditions and coformulae.

Comment: @DWin thanks, I forget to mention that if there is no match, NA will be output...the final else condition

Comment: See a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9213940/210673

Comment: @Aaron thanks for the link, I am not sure how the expression evaluation will fit here in match expression

Comment: @ramshar: I don't know what you mean by evaluation, but see TimP's answer, where he's now added code.

Comment: Did the code I provided work correctly for you?

Comment: @ramshar ... if it all worked out, fancy giving me a tick? :)

Comment: @TimP yes you diserve it...wish I could give more credits for it ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks overly complex!

My suggestion would be to make the table of conditions into a data frame with three columns: The first column would be a paste of the columns MTR, CLD, and AF (so a typical entry might be "AB~AA~AB") and the other two columns would be called COEFA and COEFAB which are the coefficient multiplying 1/a and the coefficient multiplying 1/(a+b) in your PI expression... e.g. "0.5/a" would have COEFA = 0.5 and COEFAB = 0 while "1/(a+b)" would have COEFA = 0 and COEFB = 1.

To be clear, condition 1 would be represented in the form MTR_CLD_AF = "AA~AA~AB", COEFA = 0.5, COEFB = 0.

Then to work out which condition is appropriate for each row in dataf, you just need to paste MTR, CLD and AF together, match this up to column MTR_CLD_AF in the conditions dataframe, and thereby extract COEFA and COEFB for that row. The desired value for your PI variable is then COEFA*(1/a) + COEFB*(1/(a+b)).

Let me know if further explanation or code would be helpful :)

**Follow up:**

Here's a stab at the code I'd use here:

```
### first, all your object definitions...

MTR <- c("AA",  "AA",   "AB",   "AA",   "AB",   "BB",   "AB",   "AB")
CLD <- c("AA",  "AB",   "AA",   "AA",   "AA",   "AB",   "AB",   "AB")
AF <- c("AB",   "AB",   "AB",   "AA",   "AA",   "AA",   "AA",   "AB")
PI <- c("0.5/a",    "0.5/a",    "0.5/a",    "1/a",  "1/a",  "1/a",  
      "1/(a+b)",    "1/(a+b)")

dataf <- data.frame (MTR = c("AB", "BB", "AB", "BB", "AB", "AA"),
                     CLD= c("AA", "AB", "AA", "AB", "AB", "AB"),
                     AF = c("AA", "AB", "BB", "AB", "BB", "AB")
                     )
a = c(0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4)
mapd <- data.frame(a = a, b = 1-a)

### first create COEFA and COEFAB from PI (could automate but small 
### enough to do manually here)

COEFA <- c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
COEFAB <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)

### then create conditions data frame as specified in my solution

cond = data.frame(MTR_CLD_AF = paste(MTR,CLD,AF,sep="~"), COEFA, COEFAB,
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

### now put all the data in dataf and mapd into one object alldata to 
### keep things neat

alldata = data.frame(MTR = dataf$MTR, CLD = dataf$CLD, AF = dataf$AF, 
                     a = mapd$a, b=mapd$b, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

### now go ahead and get COEFA and COEFB for each row in alldata - first 
### do the match up (look in matcond to see this) then copy coef columns 
### over to alldata

matcond=cond[match(with(alldata, paste(MTR, CLD, AF, sep="~")),
                   cond$MTR_CLD_AF),]
alldata$COEFA = matcond$COEFA
alldata$COEFAB = matcond$COEFAB

### finally compute COEFA*(1/a) + COEFAB*(1/(a+b)) using the columns of 
### alldata, and store the answer in column called PI

alldata$PI = with(alldata, COEFA*(1/a) + COEFAB*(1/(a+b)))

### that's it! as noted elsewhere, the value will be NA if no matching
### condition exists
```

Comment: thanks for the suggstion. I made some changes and the code will be helpful

Comment: @Tim P Sorry for delaying to tick the answer, I upvoted as well as ticked anwer. I wish I could give more credits !

Answer (score 2):

```
#data.frame with conditions and functions      
confun<-data.frame(c1=c("AA","AA","AB"),
                       c2=c("AA","AB","AA"),
                       c3=c("AB","AB","AB"),
                       fun=c("0.5/a","0.5/b","1/(a+b)"))
confun$fun<-as.character(confun$fun)

confun
      c1 c2 c3     fun
    1 AA AA AB   0.5/a
    2 AA AB AB   0.5/b
    3 AB AA AB   1/(a+b)

#data        
test<-data.frame(c1=c("AA","AB"),c2=c("AB","AA"),c3=c("AB","AB"),a=c(2,3))
    test$b<-1-test$a

test
  c1 c2 c3 a  b
1 AA AB AB 2 -1
2 AB AA AB 3 -2

fun<-function(c1,c2,c3) as.numeric(rownames(confun[paste(confun$c1,confun$c2,confun$c3)==paste(c1,c2,c3),]))    
test$i<-mapply(fun,test$c1,test$c2,test$c3)

fun2<-function(a,b,i) eval(parse(text=confun$fun[i]))

res<-mapply(fun2,test$a,test$b,test$i)

res
[1] -0.5  1.0
```

quick & dirty

Comment: I was surprised to revisit this answer and find a downvote. I've exerted what limited weight I can bring to bear on correcting that injustice. This seems responsive and accurate.

Comment: I am very grateful for that. I kept pondering if there is something severely wrong with the code.

Comment: @Roland I will give +1 one for your efforts to help me and correcting injustice